# Test if a for-each-group returns more than 1 group XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a for-each group like the one below, but I only want the code to execute if the result of that for-each-group has more than 1 group... How can I do this?

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="course[$department = department/@code]" group-by="course_group[@code]">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cristy, Please be aware that the answer you accepted is incorrect. You are asking about the *number of groups* but the accepted answer is testing is something different -- the number of items in the current group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="course[$department = department/@code]" group-by="course_group[@code]">
  <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) &gt; 1">
    <xsl:text>Do Something</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: FYI: I've not yet played with XSLT2, so this is a guess based on functions I've seen mentioned on the web - looks like its got a few promising features though.

Comment: It worked, i just had to change the &gt to > because it was causing me errors! thanks!

Comment: No worries - sorry, the &gt was a typo - meant to be &gt; - but >'s good too if it works (in VS2010 XSLT1.0 greater than signs in attribute values tended to be highlighted as syntax errors for some reason, so I started using special character codes by default).

Comment: @JohnLBevan, The OP is asking about the *number of groups* but what your code is testing is something different -- the number of items in the current group.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev; agreed - my interpretation of the question was that Cristy was after number per group, but I agree MichaelKay's answer is the better one if you want the number of groups.

Comment: @JohnLBevan, Don't worry, we all sometimes misinterpret a question, especially on Friday night :) What is important is to let the OP know that what he thinks is the right answer, isn't what he said he wanted.

Comment: Minor performance tip: Whenever you have an 'if' or 'when' with test="count(something > x)", you can use test="something[x+1]" instead- it returns true as soon as it finds more than x, rather than counting them all.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use last():

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="..." group-by="...">
  <xsl:if test="last() gt 1">
    ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vGroups" as="item()*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select=
   "course[$department = department/@code]" group-by="course_group[@code]"
  >1</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each-group select=
 "course[$vGroups[2]][$department = department/@code]" group-by="course_group[@code]">
    <!-- Your desired processing here -->
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

So, the first `<xsl:for-each-group>` generates an item for each group and this is captured in the `$vGroups` variable.

The second `<xsl:for-each-group>` has the added condition `[$vGroups[2]]` and will select any groups (and execute) only if the sequence `$vGroups` contains at least two items.

**Alternatively, one may use**:

```
exists(distinct-values(course[$department = department/@code]/course_group[@code])[2])
```

**Alternatively**, (why have I forgotten this) as pointed in the answer by Michael Kay, one can simply use:

```
last() gt 1
```

This third alternative is the best and recommended expression to use.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<xsl:if test="count(current-group()) > 1">
    <xsl:text>Do Something</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```